# Can I add a button to my webview for additional functionality?

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I am designing a mobile app to work with a site we already have up and running. There are a few things we would like to take advantage of on the phone, however. For example, using the camera to upload photographs to the site.

Currently, I have this code

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <WebView
             source={{uri: "https://example.com"}}
         />
    );
  }
}
```

Is there some way to add a button that lets users open a menu of options that exists on the app alone (and separate from the site in the webview).

I'v tried something like

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <WebView
             source={{uri: "https://example.com"}}
         />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

just as a test to see if I can add other elements outside the webview, but my app never loads (I just see a blank white screen) when I try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that Test and WewbView won't show up in your example code it's because View doesn't have a defined height, you can use flex:1 to give it the entire screen.
See this working sample:
https://snack.expo.io/@cgomezmendez/vengeful-tortillas

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <WebView
             source={{uri: "https://google.com"}}
         />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: So I'm seeing an error from my emulator that expo needs to be installed. I looked into the expo installation instructions, and it says that I don't need to install expo on my emulator since the expo-cli will do that for me. But it still isn't working even after I've installed expo-cli on my machine. I also want to know does this mean my users will need to install expo on their devices to use the app?

Comment: I took out the expo references in an edit because they are not relevant to the question and only create confusion.

Comment: Yes that's right, I only left it there because it was in the empty snack.expo.io project .

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at this: [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge)

Comment: I got this working, but it opens the webview outside of my own app. I wanted something that worked within my app.